# How to update c++ or g++ to version 14 or above?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, g++

How to update or install g++ 15 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Where have you found _any_ information about g++ 15? The most recent stable release is 10.2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection

Answer (score 6):

There is no `g++15`. Ubuntu 20.04 comes with `gcc-9` by default (and `gcc-10` can be installed with `sudo apt install gcc-10`). `g++` is a part of [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection#Languages).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17#Compiler_support),

> GCC has had complete support for C++17 language features since version
> 8

Therefore, `gcc-9` certainly supports C++14. There is no C++15.